# How can I create an unassignable dummy value?

Tags: php, singleton

I need a single value of a unique type, similar to C#'s [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value(v=vs.110).aspx).

I'm experimenting with how I might implement this in PHP. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
class Wild {
    public static $value;

    private function __construct() {}
}

call_user_func(function () {
    $r = new ReflectionClass(Wild::class);
    Wild::$value = $r->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
});
```

Now I can access my singleton easily via `Wild::$value`. The problem is that anyone can re-assign `Wild::$value` to something else at any time, and that would break the entire API. Is there any way to prevent this?

N.B. The constructor is private to prevent accidental instantiation. The closure is prevent `$r` from leaking out because it's in global scope.

Comment: @PleaseWait What are you asking?

Comment: @PleaseWait I still don't understand what you're trying to say. `Wild::$value` needs to be publicly accessible but developers should not be able to re-assign it to something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Wild {
    private function __construct() {}

    public static function value() {
        static $value;
        if($value === null) $value = new self;
        return $value;
    }
}
```

It's not *quite* the same, but it's probably less hacky than using reflection anyway.